# R: tm package, aggregate / join docs

Tags: r, metadata, aggregate, tm, word-frequency

I could not find any previous questions posted on this, so perhaps you can help.

What is a good way to aggregate data in a tm corpus based on metadata (e.g. aggregate texts of different writers)?

There are at least two obvious ways it could be done:

- A built-in function in tm, that would allow a DocumentTermMatrix to be built on a metadata feature. Unfortunately I haven't been able to uncover this.
- A way to join documents within a corpus based on some external metadata in a table. It would just use metadata to replace document-ids.

So you would have a table that contains: DocumentId, AuthorName

And a tm-built corpus that contains an amount of documents. I understand it is not difficult to introduce the table as metadata for the corpus object.

A matrix can be built with a following function.

```
library(tm) # version 0.6, you seem to be using an older version
corpus  <-Corpus(DirSource("/directory-with-texts"),
 readerControl = list(language="lat"))

metadata <- data.frame(DocID, Author)

#A very crude way to enter metadata into the corpus (assumes the same sequence):
for (i in 1:length(corpus)) {
  attr(corpus[[i]], "Author") <- metadata$Author[i]
}

a_documenttermmatrix_by_DocId <-DocumentTermMatrix(corpus)
```

How would you build a matrix that shows frequencies for each author possibly aggregating multiple documents instead of documents? It would be useful to do this just at this stage and not in post-processing with only a few terms.

```
a_documenttermmatrix_by_Author <- ?
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A DocumentTermMatrix is really just a matrix with fancy dressing (a Simple Triplet Matrix from the slam library) that contains term frequencies for each term and document.  Aggregating data from multiple documents by author is really just adding up the columns for the author.  Consider formatting the matrix as a standard R matrix and use standard subsetting / aggregating methods:

```
# Format the document term matrix as a standard matrix.
# The rownames of m become the document Id's
# The colnames of m become the individual terms
m <- as.matrix(dtm)

# Transpose matrix to use the "by" operator.
# Rows become individual terms
# Columns become document ids
# Group columns by Author
# Aggregate column sums (word frequencies) for each author, resulting in a list.
author.list <- by(t(m), metadata$Author, colSums)

# Format the list as a matrix and do stuff with it
author.dtm <- matrix(unlist(author.list), nrow = length(author.list), byrow = T)

# Add column names (term) and row names (author)
colnames(author.dtm) <- rownames(m)
rownames(author.dtm) <- names(author.list)

# View the resulting matrix
View(author.dtm[1:10, 1:10])
```

The resulting matrix will be a standard matrix where the rows are the Authors and the columns are the individual terms.  You should be able to do whatever analysis you want at that point.

Answer (score 0):

I have a very crude workaround for this if the corpus text can be found in a table. However this does not help a lot with a large corpus in a 'tm' format, however it may be handy in other cases. Feel free to improve it, as it is very crude!

```
custom_term_matrix <- function(author_vector, text_vector)
{
  author_vector <- factor(author_vector)
  temp <- data.frame(Author = levels(author_vector))

  for (i in 1:length(temp$Author)){
    temp$Content[i] <- paste(c(as.character(text_vector[author_vector ==
      levels(author_vector)[i]])), sep=" ", collapse="")
  }

  m <- list(id = "Author", content = "Content")
  myReader <- readTabular(mapping = m)
  mycorpus <- Corpus(DataframeSource(data1), readerControl = list(reader = myReader))

  custom_matrix <<- DocumentTermMatrix(mycorpus, control = 
    list(removePunctuation = TRUE))
}
```

There probably is a function internal to tm, that I haven't been able to find, so I will be grateful for any help!